# hAxis values fixed Google Line Chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I need to set my xAxis the following values:

```
Values : 63,80,100,125,160,200,250,315,400,500,630,800,1000,1250,1600,2000
```

The values currently displayed:

```
Values currently: 125,250,375,500,625,750,875,1000,1125,1250,1375,1500,1625,1750,1875,2000
```

My chart options:

```
 var options = {

                hAxis: {
                    minValue: 63, 
                    maxValue: 2000,
                    gridlines: {
                        count: 16
                    },
                textStyle: {fontSize: 10},
                slantedText:true, 
                slantedTextAngle:90
            }
```

}

As I can specify values xAxis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options), you can use `hAxis.ticks`...

Change your `hAxis` options as follows:

```
var options = {
    hAxis: {
        gridlines: {count: 16},
        textStyle: {fontSize: 10},
        slantedText: true, 
        slantedTextAngle: 90,
        ticks: [63,80,100,125,160,200,250,315,400,500,630,800,1000,1250,1600,2000]
    }
}
```

Comment: @IvanJavierBarrancoGavilan were you able to correct your chart?